# Is there any polynomial solution for Subset-Sum?

Tags: subset, knapsack-problem, subset-sum

Is there any polynomial solution for subset sum problem for 100 numbers ?

Comment: Subset sum is NP-complete, so the is no known polynomial time algorithm that works on every set of numbers. But since your sets are limited to 100 numbers, you can also use a non polynomial time algorithm. Maybe you can also look for approximation algorithms. Subset sum can be approximated very well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I want to find the exact solution.